# Why would pytest be running full code rather than tests when I click "Run Tests"?

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest, vscode-extensions

I've tried to google this but nothing helpful is coming up.

Basically I have an src folder, and within it are two modules - app.py and app_test.py. In app, there are about 17 functions, and I've written a test for one of them in app_test. A very simple one that checks whether a filepath is being created properly.

But when I click on "Run Tests", what happens? My whole app.py code runs. I tried with UnitTests instead and get an error that a relative path doesn't exist...which is not referenced anywhere in app_test or the simple test that exists in there on its own. The same thing happens if I run pytest src/app_test.py from the command line.

I'm assuming I've set something up wrong but can't work out what!

Comment: Probably because you have code in `app.py` on script level that runs on import and should be put under `if __name__ == "__main__":`.

Comment: @hoefling thank you so much! I knew it'd be something simple. life saver :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hoefling solved it in the comments! probably super obvious to most but in case anybody else is struggling -

Probably because you have code in app.py on script level that runs on import and should be put under if **name** == "**main**":